# Rendering TIF files in HTML

Tags: html, image, tiff

I'm building a utility which will pull TIF files from blob storage and render them in html. Since it's just a utility, I will view them in Edge, which shows TIF files.

I can see the eighth example on [this page](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html) renders fine. Meaning, this code works:

```
<img width=200 height=200 
  src="tiffdocument.tif" alt="">
```

However, my HTML, below, does not render anything:

```
<img src="https://atpblob.blob.core.windows.net/imagedata/94ae9802-4e42-4ba1-8955-11ac7c7e3509.tif" alt="" width="500" height="500">
```

If I go directly to the link in the source, it will download the image, so why won't it render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

img does not work the way I was trying to use it. You have to explicitly use a GET request to pull the file.

For rendering the file cross-browser, I ended up using [tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js).

The final html/js/css string I pushed to the browser ended up looking like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>TIF View</title>
</head>
<body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/seikichi/tiff.js/f03d7965/tiff.min.js"></script>
      <script>
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
              xhr.open('GET', 'https://atpblob.blob.core.windows.net/imagedata/${blob}.tif');
              xhr.onload = function (e) {
                                var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
                                var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
                                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                            };
              xhr.send(null);
       </script>
       <style>
              canvas {
                      min-height: 60px;
                      }
       </style>
  </body>
```